# Load SharePoint Online new UI experience

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have ben using SharePoint online for couple of days. I have changed the UI to classic 2013 view. Is there any way I can again switch it back to new UI experience ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete the cookie that tells SharePoint to display in classic mode.

Pop open the developer tools by pressing F12 and switch to the (JavaScript) console, then enter the following:

```
document.cookie = "splnu=; Path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
```

Refresh the page and you should be back on the modern view.

Comment: @Vaibhav Great! Don't forget to mark this as an answer so other people know that your question has been answered.